# Brackets and git integration

Tags: git, adobe-brackets

I want to use brackets with git as my source control.

When I open brackets on its default folder (Getting started) I click the init button or clone to create my repository.

So I opened a new folder on my desktop and switched from the default folder to my new one on brackets but then I dont see those buttons anymore, instead I have a really lot files marked as unstaged like this folder is a repo but I didnt create any repo.

Comment: The tag description of "brackets": "Brackets are tall punctuation marks used in matched pairs within text, to set apart or interject other text. They have a variety of meanings in different programming languages. ***DO NOT USE THIS for the IDE, use [adobe-brackets] instead.***"

Answer (score 0):

> instead I have a really lot files marked as unstaged like this folder is a repo but I didn't create any repo.

You have created the git repo in the parent directory so you see all the files on your desktop !!!!

delete the `.git` folder from your desktop and do a `git init` in your desired folder.

Comment: I didnt create any repo.. There isnt .git folder on my desktop, only in the getting started folder